# Google ads not working in Firefox and Windows 8

Tags: firefox, ads, adsense

Google adsense ads are not displaying in Firefox when on Windows 8. The ads will display in Firefox for XP but not in Windows 8. Both operating systems are running Firefox 18.0.1. Any insight in resolving this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First step: Look at HTTP requests and JS errors.

Comment: @SLaks Firebug is not showing any errors or anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Adblock Plus add-on for Firefox that was disabling the ads.